# Bitmain S9 BMMINER does not respond to Stratum set_difficulty command

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, miner-configuration, stratum

We use a modified version of [this library](https://github.com/fireduck64/SockThing) to implement the [first SHA256 multi+merge mining pool](https://crypto-trade.net/pool).

It works just fine with the S7 which has `CGMiner 4.8 ("cgminer/4.8.0")`.
However, the S9 with `BMMINER 2 ("bmminer/2.0.0")` is either unable to connect, either connects, and remains on the initial difficulty of shares, and thus all work gets rejected.

We suspect that the `BMMINER` does not support the `set_difficulty` method.
The question is, how can this be solved? can we use s7 firmware for s9, or find a `CGMiner` compatible with S9 anywhere?